# Search for an element in an excel table and print its information organized in a pdf file

Tags: java, excel

I have an Microsoft excel worksheet with some data in it of the form: 
`String`-`String`-`Integer` and I want to be able to choose an item and then print its info in pdf in this format:

Name: `String`
Date: `String`
ID: `int`

Is it possible? If yes, how? If no, are there some java libraries  that would allow me to do that?

Comment: It would be nice to know if you just tried something out, if yes, please edit your Question and add the relevant code, make sure it is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can verify. Otherwise it would be nice to have an idea how the structure of your `xls` looks like, which type of elements (String, double, Dates, ??? ) you want to find within the `xls`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will add more details in my question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i would like to give you a small example, which can find a String Value on an `XLS` document:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

/**
 *
 * @author Patrick Ott <Patrick.Ott@professional-webworkx.de>
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class App {

    public static final String USER_HOME = System.getProperty("user.home");

    public static final void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            // change the path, where your xls file is located
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(USER_HOME + "/test/workbook.xls"));
            // create a new Workbook
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            // get the first Sheet, if you have more, then 1 or 2 or ....
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            // go through all rows
            for (int i = 0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
                if (sheet.getRow(i) != null) {
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                    // get the last cell of the current row
                    short lastCellNum = row.getLastCellNum();
                    for(int j = 0; j < lastCellNum; j++) {
                         // if the current column is != null and contains a String and 
                         // equals("Espresso") (i added this for test in my example) then
                         // print "Found", here you can start to create the PDF
                        if(row.getCell(j) != null && row.getCell(j).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING && row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Espresso")) {
                            System.out.println("Found");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to work with Maven, then here is the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.professional_webworkx.apachepoi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApachePOIDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.11</version>
     </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Otherwise you have to add the Apache POI Jar's manually to your project.

For creating PDF Files with Java, you can have a look at [iText](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext) or at [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) both libraries have also Maven Dependencies, which you can add to your `pom.xml`.

I hope this will help you to start with your own app, if you have special problems, ask again, but make sure, that the question wont be answered alright.

Patrick

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code my friend, I already started exploring iText and Apache POI. Just one more question, Is what I am trying to accomplish possible using the Excel's vba (Adding a button that gets data from a selected row and saves it as pdf)?

Comment: @user3654191 you mean adding a Button with VBA functionality to your Excel Sheet and get data from the selected row and save it to a pdf file? That has nothing to do with Java, therefor you need to work on your VBA script.